# How can I have multiple wiremock instances sharing the same journal

Tags: wiremock

I'm running wiremock in standalone mode (using spring-cloud-contract-wiremock) in an infrastructure that allows me to scale the number of instances and place them under a load balancer.

Until now I was just using it to send back canned responses to some test cases, but now I want to verify that some requests were processed. Which is not working, because of the in memory nature of the journal + the round robin load balancing

Is there a way to share the request journal among multiple instances (for instance having it shared on DB or file mount)?

I've had to scale down my wiremock setup to just one node, which allowed this particular test to pass, but will have detrimental impact in the overal test suite performance

Comment: You might be better off trying to tune the WireMock instance and your stubs rather than scaling it horizontally unless you're running a load test generating > 1k req/second.